# Exception when referencing WCF in MonoDevelop that exposes System.Data.DataSet

Tags: monodevelop

When referencing our test WCF service I get this error in MonoDevelop (2.4 and 2.6).
We are exposing `System.Data.DataSet` and it seems to dislike that. Is it a known issue with MonoDevelop? Is there a workaround?
I can reference the same service in Studio 2008 just fine.

> Only local element is allowed as the content of the sequence of the
>   top-level content of a complex type
>   'http://tempuri.org/:GetDataResult'. Other particles (sequence,
>   choice, all, any, group ref) are not supported.

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Only local element is allowed as the content of the sequence of the top-level content of a complex type 'http://tempuri.org/:GetDataResult'. Other particles (sequence, choice, all, any, group ref) are not supported.
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractImporter.ImportComplexType (System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration td, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet schemas, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaComplexType type, System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName qname) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractImporter.DoImport (System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet schemas, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaType type, System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName qname) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractImporter.Import (System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet schemas, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaType type, System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName qname) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractImporter.Import (System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet schemas, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaElement element) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter.CreateMessagePart (System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaElement elem) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter.ImportPartsBySchemaElement (System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName qname, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 parts, System.String ns) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter.resolveMessage (System.Web.Services.Description.Message msg, System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageBodyDescription body, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 parts) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter.DoImportContract () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter.System.ServiceModel.Description.IWsdlImportExtension.ImportContract (System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlImporter importer, System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlContractConversionContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlImporter.ImportContract (System.Web.Services.Description.PortType wsdlPortType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlImporter.ImportAllContracts () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.WCF.WebServiceDiscoveryResultWCF.CreateProxyFile (MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject dotNetProject, FilePath basePath, System.String proxyNamespace, System.String referenceName) [0x0014d] in /Users/michael/Mono/md-2-5-90/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.WebReferences/MonoDevelop.WebReferences.WCF/WebServiceDiscoveryResultWCF.cs:176 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.WebServiceDiscoveryResult.GenerateFiles (MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject project, System.String namspace, System.String referenceName) [0x0008b] in /Users/michael/Mono/md-2-5-90/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.WebReferences/MonoDevelop.WebReferences/WebServiceDiscoveryResult.cs:89 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.Commands.WebReferenceCommandHandler.NewWebReference () [0x000b8] in /Users/michael/Mono/md-2-5-90/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.WebReferences/MonoDevelop.WebReferences.Commands/WebReferenceCommandHandler.cs:43
```